# Which OutputStream subclass to write to a text file

Tags: java, file, ascii, outputstream

[Assignment]

**Requirement**

Use *specifically* **OutputStream subclasses** to output data to a .txt file, that can be read by a person using a program like Notepad.
(so a Writer is not an option)

**Thoughts**

May be ASCII or any human-readable character set.

**Question**

Which one of these do I use?

- ByteArrayOutputStream
- FileOutputStream
- FilterOutputStream
- ObjectOutputStream
- OutputStream
- PipedOutputStream

Comment: OutputStreamWriter wrapped in a BufferedWriter?

Comment: Why specifically ASCII? Notepad supports for example UTF-8 as well.

Comment: Well, sure, anything that can be understood and uses any of those subclasses.

Comment: In my (deleted) answer it turns out that this is actually a homework assignment and that OP isn't allowed to use a `Writer` as a normal developer would do. I added the homework tag. Now, have you read the javadocs from each one mentioned to learn what each one should be used for? Start here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html

Comment: Yes, thanks, I have read the javadocs of course, anything else before asking here and stealing time from people.

Comment: Okay, can you please edit your question to add an overview of what all those classes should be used for and why you think that it would be (in)suitable for writing text files? For example, "ByteArrayOutputStream is insuitable because it can only write to a byte[] in memory, not to a file", and so on. Then we can eventually correct you accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) is to write bytes to an in-memory `byte[]` variable.
- The [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) is to write bytes to a [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html).
- The [`FilterOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html) is a common superclass for more specific output streams which manipulate the data beforehand, such as encryption/decryption, calculating checksum, character encoding, compressing (zipping), etcetera. It does by itself nothing special.
- The [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) is to write fullworthy Java types and objects in a serialized form into a byte stream. It basically allows to convert complex Java objects to raw bytes and vice versa.
- The [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html) is just the common abstract class of those streams. You can't construct it anyway. You can however declare against it.
- The [`PipedOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) is intented to be able to write to another `InputStream` in a pipe so that the other side can read them from that `InputStream`.

You want to write the data plain to a [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html), so the [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) is more than sufficient.

```
try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/foo.txt")) {
    output.write(text.getBytes());
}
```

Note that [`String#getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) uses the platform default encoding to convert characters to bytes. If you're using "special characters" which are not covered by at least ASCII, then you should always explicitly specify the charset using [`String#getBytes(charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)). E.g.:

```
    output.write(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, the *normal practice*, however, is to use a [`Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Writer.html) to write character data.

If you don't care about character encoding, use [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html):

```
try (Writer writer = new FileWriter("/foo.txt")) {
    writer.write(text);
}
```

It will use the platform default character encoding which will usually also support ASCII characters.

If you care about character encoding, use [`OutputStreamWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html):

```
try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("/foo.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    // ...
}
```

It allows you for specifying the charset as 2nd argument while taking an `OutputStream`.

#### See also:

- [Java Basic I/O tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: well, thank you very much, but I have this assignment that asks me to use one of OutputStream subclasses specifically...

Comment: Thanks you, that really explained a lot.
However, there is also the other OutputStream: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/portable/OutputStream.html

Comment: There are countless implementations. I only really wonder what kind of teacher would mention the CORBA one as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [PrintStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). It is a subclass of OutputStream and allows for line-by-line output. It is the same class used in System.out

```
new PrintStream(new File("path/to/your/file.txt")).println("Your output");
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything wrong with FileOutputStream?